# How to use jQuery wrap in jQuery variables?

Tags: jquery, html

I am struggling to understand how does the jQuery `wrap()` method work. In the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) I find this:

> Description: Wrap an HTML structure around each element in the set of matched elements.

I saw their examples. I tested it with elements from the page. It works fine, but my question is: *can I use `wrap()` for **jQuery variables?***

I have the following test code:

```
var d = $("<div class='one'>");
d.html("Hi, I am <strong>strong</strong>");

console.log("Before wrapping: ", d.html());
d.wrap("<div class='new'></div>");

console.log("After wrapping: ", d.html());
```

This outputs:

> `Before wrapping:  Hi, I am <strong>strong</strong>`
>
> `After wrapping:  Hi, I am <strong>strong</strong>`

The first output is correct. For the second one **I expected**:

> `After wrapping:  <div class='one'>Hi, I am <strong>strong</strong></div>`

(because it was wrapped with `<div class='new'></div>`)

What am I doing wrong?

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/q9HqX/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you are wrapping `d` with another element `d` still refers to the old element set, if you want to have the wrapped element html then you have to access the parent of `d` and then get the html like

```
console.log("Parent: ", d.parent().html());
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/J937k/)